# How to configure log4j with a properties file

Tags: java, properties, log4j

How do I get log4j to pick up a properties file.

I'm writing a Java desktop app which I want to use log4j. In my main method if have this:

```
   PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

The log4j.properties file sits in the same directory when I open the Jar.

Yet I get this error:

> log4j:ERROR Could not read
>   configuration file [log4j.properties].
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   log4j.properties (The system cannot
>   find the file specified)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The log4j.properties file must be in the root folder of your main application (since you're writing a desktop application).

Answer (score 52):

I believe that the configure method expects an absolute path. Anyhow, you may also try to load a Properties object first:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("log4j.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

If the properties file is in the jar, then you could do something like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

The above assumes that the log4j.properties is in the root folder of the jar file.

Comment: An absolute path in the jar or  the filesystem?

Comment: An absolute path in the filesystem. Use getResource if the file is in the jar.

Answer (score 13):

When you use PropertyConfigurator.configure(**String configFilename**),
they are the following operation in the log4j library.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
FileInputStream istream = null;
try {
  istream = new FileInputStream(configFileName);
  props.load(istream);
  istream.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
...
```

It fails in reading because it looks for "Log4j.properties" from the current directory where the application is executed.

How about the way that it changes the reading part of the property file as follows, and puts "log4j.properties" on the directory to which the CLASSPATH is set.

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = loader.getResource("log4j.properties");
PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
```

Another method of putting "Log4j.properties" in the jar file exists.

```
jar xvf [YourApplication].jar log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 11):

just set  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties worked for me.

log4j then looks for the *file* log4j.properties in the current working directory of the application.

Remember that log4j.configuration is a *URL* specification, so add 'file:' in front of your log4j.properties filename if you want to refer to a regular file on the filesystem, i.e. a file not on the classpath!

Initially I specified  -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties. However that only works if log4j.properties is on the classpath. When I copied log4j.properties to main/resources in my project and rebuild so that it was copied to the target directory (maven project) this worked as well (or you could package your log4j.properties in your project jars, but that would not allow the user to edit the logger configuration!).

Comment: easy and clean :)

Answer (score 4):

This is an edit of the answer from @kgiannakakis:
The original code is wrong because it does not correctly close the InputStream after `Properties.load(InputStream)` is called.  From the Javadocs: `The specified stream remains open after this method returns.`

================================

I believe that the configure method expects an absolute path. Anyhow, you may also try to load a Properties object first:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("log4j.properties");
try {
    props.load(is);
}
finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore this exception
    }
}
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

If the properties file is in the jar, then you could do something like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties");
try {
    props.load(is);
}
finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore this exception
    }
}
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

The above assumes that the log4j.properties is in the root folder of the jar file.

Answer (score 3):

I have this code in my application today

```
File log4jfile = new File("./conf/log4j.properties");
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

The relative path is from the working directory of the JVM (where the JVM starts).

Answer (score 1):

```java
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
```

Import this, then:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties");

try {
    props.load(is);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ignore this exception
    log.error("Unable to load log4j properties file.",e);
}
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

My java files directory like this:

```
src/main/java/com/abc/xyz
```

And log4j directory like this:

```java
src/main/resources
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the log4j.properties directory it needs to be in the java classpath. In your case adding the CWD to the classpath *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Since JVM arguments are eventually passed to your java program as system variables, you can use this code at the beginning of your execution point to edit the property and have log4j read the property you just set in system properties

```
try {
        System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"conf"+File.separator+"log4j.properties").toURI().toURL().toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **log4j.properties** location is like *path/to/configfiles/log4j.properties*.
Then simply use,

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("path/to/configfiles/log4j.properties");
```

Also, if the path is *src/main/resources/log4j.properties* then even this code is not required since it is the default location.

Answer (score -3):

You can enable log4j internal logging by defining the '**log4j.debug**' variable.

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury Nope, but its a valuable alternative that should be documented.  But keep wasting your reputation on downgrades... you've only got a couple hundred million to go!

Comment: It's not personal,but i completely understand why people don't comment after downgrading. :)