# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PatterLayout

Tags: java, log4j

After fixing by old issue i have gave a fix what specified in this link

[How to configure log4j with a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file) but now i am facing a new issue i.e

I get the following Error Messge:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.PatterLayout].

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PatterLayout
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:169)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:317)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:120)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:641)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:509)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:441)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:336)
    at com.akak.book.shop.listener.JlcindiaContextListener.contextInitialized(JlcindiaContextListener.java:33)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Can any one help me out off this please .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spelled `PatternLayout` wrong in your log4j.properties. You are missing the "N"!