# cant get log4j to run in play! framework 2.2.1 (scala project)

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, log4j

I cant get log4j to run in play framework 2.2.1

I use the following log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.logger.deng=INFO
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

application.conf:

```
application.log=INFO
application.log.path=/log4j.properties
```

scala usage example:

```
object SomeService {

  private val log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())

  def someMethod() = {
      log.error("test")
  }
}
```

If I run a test I get the following console output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (SomeService.class).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: at least by default, Play 2 uses the logback library via the slf4j api. any reason not to use that?

Comment: Gotta load the properties file.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get rid of the log4J stuff (which is so 2008) and just use the Logback via SLF4J that comes with Play. [Even the authors of log4j would tell you that](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html) because they are also the authors of Logback.

Then create an [alternative logback configuration file](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) called `application-logger.xml` and copy that to the *conf* folder of your Play application so it gets loaded on deploy.

For more information on configuring Logback with the Play! framework, see [Configuring logging](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's required or if Play/Logback default to finding it, but in our application we explicitly set "logback.configurationFile=application-logger.xml" in our application.conf. Thought I'd mention it, just in case.

Comment: Update: Play will, by default, load conf/application-logger.xml or conf/logger.xml

Comment: Not so in 2.3.x Play! Such files are not picked up, sadly.

Comment: What if I want the logs of an API to be printed and that API uses log4j?

Comment: Logback doesn't play well with Spark, and some projects need both play and Spark