# log4j - pointing to one out of multiple log4j.properties file

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

My code has a dependency on abc.jar file which internally uses log4j.jar and needs a configuration file. This configuration is used to set some of the required fields like ssl protocol, cert validate, port and also has a parameter, named *debug*, which is read by log4j.properties file (inside the abc.jar) to set the level of the logging. 
The value of the *debug* parameter is restricted to `all` or `none`. Also, the abc.jar file has its own (custom) Logger class. So whenever I create an object of `org.apache.log4j.Logger` class, it creates object of the (custom) Logger class inside the abc.jar file. I guess because of this Log4j is unable to read my log4j.properties file.

I want to use my own log4j.properties file so that I can specify the level of logging. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property `log4j.configurationFile` to set the path of your config file you want to use.

On command line, you can write `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=<path>`

Doing that disables automatic configuration and use your manually set file for configuration

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. How can I verify if that file is read?

Comment: Are you sure to set the correct path for the file according to the working directory ? You can try to use full absolute path. I see no other reason this is not working. Except if is re-set/configure programmatically in source code

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file) post? Uses PropertyConfigurator to set the log4j path in any init() like method.