# How to read log4j properties file out of classpath

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I am facing a task to put `log4j.properties` configuration file to the JBoss server instead of putting this configuration to the project as stated in official JBoss documentation here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/231514

If I got this right, log4j logger finds configuration within classpath automatically, but what is the way (if there is any) of loading this file from server directory (e.g. `wildfly/modules/x/y/log4j.properties`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:[path-to-your-external-file]` while starting the server.

This is the answer I was looking for.