# How to reconfigure logger (log4j2) with a java.util.Properties object created from a string?

Tags: java, logging, java-8, log4j, log4j2

Migrating from log4j to log4j2. Previously, the following function is called, after creating the Logger object.

```
public static void getLog4JSettingsFromString(String configString) throws IOException {
    Properties log4j = new java.util.Properties();
    log4j.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(configString.getBytes()));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4j);
}
```

Comment: Hi Please have a look of this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file

Comment: Hi, that is for log4j 1.x, the code I have is for that and it works fine. What I need is a solution for the same problem on log4j 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

To configure Log4j 2.x you need to obtain a [`Configuration`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration.html) from a [`ConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html):

```java
final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(configString);
final LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
final ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(is);
final Configuration config = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory().getConfiguration(context, source);
Configurator.reconfigure(config);
```

There are two factories named `PropertiesConfigurationFactory`:

- one that supports the Log4j 2.x configuration syntax:

  ```java
  import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory;
  ```
- one that supports (a subset of) the Log4j 1.x configuration syntax:

  ```java
  import org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfigurationFactory;
  ```

  and requires the [`log4j-1.2-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api) dependency.