# Log4j2 read properties from an external property file

Tags: java

I have an application that i have to deliver in a packaged JAR which is then run by the client in a complicated environment that makes editing env variables or JVM arguments very cumbersome (additionally client is not too technical). Currently we are using some external proeprty files for configuring the database and so on and this is going well so far.

I would like to allow the client to configure some aspects of Log4j2 using these properties files, i can see that Log4j2 allows multiple ways of performing property substitutions https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

I can also see that it is possible to load property bundles but if i understand the docs correctly these bundles need to be loaded from classpath and i have not stumbled upon a possibility of define this properties file by giving its direct path (such as "load the properties file /tmp/myconfig.properties").

So ultimately - is it possible to use variables from an external .properties file that is NOT in classpath but in a specified filesystem location? Or maybe some other way exists to load this data from external file? (i already noted that using env variables or jvm arguments is out of the question in my case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure log4j with a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file)

Comment: Nope since it is about reconfiguring entire log4j not loading external property file for property substitution.

Comment: The topic I linked shows a way of reading a properties file into a standard Properties object, and feeding it into Log4j. Can you not read the user file first (with the few variables - you can even filter them how you want) and then your apps properties file? Just an idea.

Comment: Seems that this topic is for older version of log4j class PropertyConfigurator does not exist anymore